# How to highlight mouse pointer position using Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to create a simple mouse pointer highlighter. A circle centered at the mouse pointer. It must be semi-transparent and visible everywhere (in and out of my application).

Any idea is appreciated.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is a pure Win32 question that has nothing to do with Delphi in particular; the answer would be the same in C++, for instance.

Comment: Anyhow: A very simple approach would be to create a semi-transparent window and have it track the cursor.

Comment: Create a `TForm` with a background color and a yellow circle on it. Set the Form's `TransparentColor` and `AlphaBlend` properties as needed. Then use a timer, or a Win32 hook, to move the `TForm` around the screen wherever the mouse cursor currently is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I believe this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, I cannot resist writing this short answer, because it is not only easy -- but *surprisingly* easy -- to make a primitive implementation of this using almost nothing but the VCL.

The idea is to have a semi-transparent, borderless form (window) that follows the mouse cursor. An ordinary `TTimer` updates the form's position many times each second.

Create a new VCL application. In addition to your main form, also create another form, `MouseDiscForm`, with the following properties:

```
object MouseDiscForm: TMouseDiscForm
  AlphaBlend = True
  AlphaBlendValue = 127
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  ClientHeight = 64
  ClientWidth = 64
  Color = clWhite
  TransparentColor = True
  TransparentColorValue = clWhite
  FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
  object Shape1: TShape
    Align = alClient
    Brush.Color = clYellow
    Pen.Style = psClear
    Shape = stCircle
  end
end
```

Override the form's `CreateParams` method:

```
procedure TMouseDiskForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;
```

Then in your main form, simply add a `TTimer` with `Interval = 50` and this `OnTimer` handler:

```
procedure TForm6.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var CP := Mouse.CursorPos;
  SetWindowPos(
    MouseDiscForm.Handle,
    HWND_TOPMOST,
    CP.X - MouseDiscForm.Width div 2,
    CP.Y - MouseDiscForm.Height div 2,
    0,
    0,
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE
  );
end;
```

I am sure there are a few additional details one has to consider, but generally I do find this very primitive approach to work quite well.

[image: Screen recording]

Comment: FYI, the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style is handled by the Form's `TransparentColor...` and `AlphaBlend...` properties, so you don't need to enable it manually in `CreateParams()`. Also, why would you put the `TTimer` on the MainForm and not on the `TMouseDiskForm` itself?

Comment: @RemyLebeau `CreateParams` however is needed in older Delphi versions, like D7 (and so is `GetCursorPos()`).

Comment: @AmigoJack the `AlphaBlend...` and `TransparentColor...` properties were added to `TForm` in D/CB 6, so only code for D/CB 5 and earlier would have to resort to enabling `WS_EX_LAYERED` manually in order to call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` directly. Either way, `TMouse.CursorPos` existed in D/CB 5, maybe even earlier.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the properties. But the compiled program eats every click without overriding `CreateParams()` - compile it yourself in D7 because I did so. Yes, I can verify: in D5 `TMouse.CursorPos` exists (and simply wraps `Windows.GetCursorPos()`).

Comment: You must add `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` in every version of Windows and VCL I know of. But @Remy is right that `WS_EX_LAYERED` is superfluous.

Comment: @AmigoJack "*the compiled program eats every click without overriding `CreateParams()`*" - As it should be. Just because a window is alpha-blended/translucent does not mean it is not clickable. What you are suggesting requires only `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` be added (which has nothing to do with alpha/translucency) so that clicks fall-through the window. Just be [aware of its gotchas](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823). Making `WM_NCHITTEST` return `HTTRANSPARENT` would be another option.